# How do you design a listing or aggregate of rows that are stored in different datacenters?

Tags: database, web-services, distributed, aggregation

I know one might be inclined to jump to the obvious solution and suggest we just create a central database, but that is not possible.

Here are some details to the problem.

- Post Snowden, people do not want their data in certain countries (others require data to be strictly in their territory)
- We still need to show some lists that search in all data
- We still need to report and aggregate metadata for monthly, quarterly, yearly stuff

Right now we are using a single entity list, that references the datacenter. This helps with discovery, but not with listing and aggregation.

Anyone ever cracked that?

I know we could just split the domain and require customers to be region-locked, but that would create many migration and operational headaches.